# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'attr'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to grab my divs with the class tooltip.

And then do something like this:

```
var schemes = $(".tooltip");

for (var i in schemes) {
    var scheme = schemes[i];
    console.log(scheme.attr("cost"));
}
```

But it throws the above error. What am i missing? (Im new to javascript + jquery obviously)

Comment: `.attr()` only exists on a jquery object, not on a DOM object. `schemes[i]` gets a DOM object. And, never use `for x in obj` to iterate an array.  It iterates all properties, not just array elements.  Use `.eq(i)` to get a jquery object.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you use `for-loop` to iterate jQuery set, you should get the elements with `eq()` method, but not using square bracket notation (i.e. `[]`). The code like `$(".tooltip")[i]` will pick up DOM elements, but *not* jQuery objects.

```
var schemes = $(".tooltip");
for (var i = 0; i < schemes.length; i++) {
    var scheme = schemes.eq(i);
    console.log(scheme.attr("cost"));
}
```

However, you may always use `each()` to iterate jQuery set:

```
$(".tooltip").each(function() {
    var scheme = $(this);
    console.log(scheme.attr("cost"));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var schemes = $(".tooltip");

schemes.each(function(index, elem) {
    console.log($(elem).attr('cost'));
});
```

As a sidenote "cost" is not a valid attribute for any element as far as I know, and you should probably be using data attributes.