# Getting array index of "children" doesn't allow further jQuery use

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following, and it appears to work:

```
$(element).parent().children('ul').children('li').children('a:first').attr('href')
```

this selects the first li but I wanted to do this:

```
$(element).parent().children('ul').children('li')[1].children('a:first').attr('href')
```

So I can pass in the index number but doing this gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Property 'children' of object #<HTMLLIElement> is not a function
```

Comment: Use `.eq(1)` instead of `[1]`.

Comment: As said by others, use `eq(1)`.  Using `[1]` will return you the DOM element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'attr'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533089/uncaught-typeerror-object-htmldivelement-has-no-method-attr)

Comment: @BlackSheep:should not this be eq(0)??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar The point was introducing the `eq()` method. Yes, for teh first element, `eq(0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`children('li')[1]` will return a dom object ,hence to select first item use [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method

```
$(element).parent().children('ul').children('li').eq(0).children('a:first').attr('href')
```

Comment: `.eq(1)` would select the second `li`. The index starts at 0. `.eq(0)`.

Comment: @AfromanJ `[1]` will also select 2 element :) array index also starts with 0

Comment: _"[1] will also select 2 element"_, it returns the second DOM element and just this.

Comment: Thank you, that explained exactly what i was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You need `.eq` selector:

```
$(element).parent().children('ul').children('li').eq(0).children('a:first').attr('href');
```

`eq(0)` will select the first li element.

**[see docs](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

When you give the index that dont return a jquery object you need to do like this

```
 $($(element).parent().children('ul').children('li')[1]).children('a:first').attr('href')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `first()` you're getting a raw HTML element.

```
// returns a jQuery collection of li elements
$('li');

// returns the first item in the collection, which is just an li
$('li').first();
```

[first() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

To keep chaining jQuery methods, you'll want to get the first item, not as raw HTML, but as a jQuery object.

```
// returns the first item in the collection as a jQuery object
$('li').eq(0);
```

[eq() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)